# codeigniter form validation for checkbox at least one selection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know how to make a form validation for each of inputs in codeigniter. But is it possible to make a validation for multiple checkbox where the user should select at least one check box?

example

```
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Mon
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Tues
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Wed
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Thur
```

where the codeigniter should validate that the user should select at least one checkbox.?

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Mon
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Tues
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Wed
<input type=checkbox name=days[] >Thur
```

Use following code to validate above HTML :

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('days[]', 'days', 'required');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following codes:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('days', 'days', 'required');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Check if user has selected at least one checkbox manually
if ( isset($_POST['days'])
{
//some validation errors
}
```

or you can simply do it using validation rules like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('days', 'Days Label', 'required');
```